# how to change character length in execute file for postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am executing a sql query into a file in postgreSQL 9.6.

I have a column that brings back a string (select query), but it cuts it of after a certain length.  Is there a setting to set the length that is returned in the file so that it will not cut of my string ?

**Edit**

A Sample query:

```
select columnname(querytext) from table 
where column1 = 'active'
```

Comment: Show us your code (**[edit]** your question don't post code in comments)

Comment: Which tool do you use to run the statement?

Comment: I am using pgAdmin III

Comment: That is the fault of pgAdmin III, which truncates data. Use `psql` to get the whole result.